# Django DecimalField fails to save even though I give it a floating number

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
class WithdrawRequests(models.Model):
    withdraw_hash = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, db_index=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, db_index=True)
    user_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=300, default=0.0, decimal_places=150)
    withdraw_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, db_index=True)
    withdraw_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, default=0.0, decimal_places=15)
```

This is my models.py file.

```
            currency = request.data['currency']
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
            user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
            timestamp = timestamp.timestamp()
            withdraw_hash = hashlib.sha256()
            withdraw_hash.update(str(timestamp).encode("utf-8"))
            withdraw_hash = withdraw_hash.hexdigest()
            username = user.username
            currency_balance = GAME_CURRENCIES[request.data['currency']]
            user_balance = getattr(user, currency_balance)
            withdraw_address = request.data['withdraw_address']
            withdraw_amount = request.data['withdraw_amount']

            if user_balance < withdraw_amount:
                return Response({
                            "message": "Not enough funds."
                        })
            else:
                # row format - hash timestamp username currency user_balance withdraw_address withdraw_amount
                withdraw = WithdrawRequests()
                withdraw.withdraw_hash = withdraw_hash,
                withdraw.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(),
                withdraw.username = username,
                withdraw.currency = currency,
                withdraw.user_balance = user_balance,
                withdraw.withdraw_address = withdraw_address,
                withdraw.withdraw_amount = withdraw_amount

                withdraw.save()
```

And here is the views.py file. Whatever I do the error is the following.

```
   ...

  File "C:\Users\Msi\cover_game\cover\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1554, in to_python
    raise exceptions.ValidationError(
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“(0.011095555563904999,)” value must be a decimal number.']
```

As you can see with user_balance everything is fine and it's floating number.

Edited: added the whole view and the other model so that it will be more clear.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add a [mre]. Also what is the data you have posted?

Comment: **Typo:** you're ending some of your lines with a `,` like: `withdraw.user_balance = user_balance,` that creates a **one tuple**. Note: an [mre] means your example should also be _minimal_ the code you have shared has too many extra things. It also includes _reproducible_ which means we should be able to copy paste and run it (Your example has some variables whose declaration aren't shown).

Comment: Abdul Aziz barkat is right your code in else condition where you are saving the model has some `,` which creates tuple, kindly remove all that.

Comment: @SunderamDubey asked me to share the whole view, I said it will be huge but anyways.

Comment: Remove commas as stated.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I removed the commas and it worked. Thank you very much. Sometimes I can't understand Django's error messages, I got so worked up and didn't sleep for 26 hours that didn't even notice the commas.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat should I delete this question? I edited it removed the the unnecessary parts.

Comment: I haven't noticed the commas either :-( apologies.

Comment: @SunderamDubey it happens even with the best :)

Answer (score 1):

`“(0.011095555563904999,)”` looks like string value, not float.
You should clean the `withdraw_amount` variable by removing braces, quotes and comma.

Comment: if I doprint( type(user_balance)) it outputs float

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your views:

```py
x=request.data["withdraw_amount"]
num_list="0123456789."
actual_str=""
for i,k in enumerate(x):
    if k in num_list:
        actual_str+=k
withdraw_amount=float(actual_str)
print(withdraw_amount)
```

So:

```py
currency = request.data['currency']
        payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
        user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
        timestamp = timestamp.timestamp()
        withdraw_hash = hashlib.sha256()
        withdraw_hash.update(str(timestamp).encode("utf-8"))
        withdraw_hash = withdraw_hash.hexdigest()
        username = user.username
        currency_balance = GAME_CURRENCIES[request.data['currency']]
        user_balance = getattr(user, currency_balance)
        withdraw_address = request.data['withdraw_address']
        
        x=request.data["withdraw_amount"]
        num_list="0123456789."
        actual_str=""
        for i,k in enumerate(x):
            if k in num_list:
                actual_str+=k
   
        withdraw_amount=float(actual_str)
        print(withdraw_amount)

        if user_balance < withdraw_amount:
            return Response({
                            "message": "Not enough funds."
                        })
        else:
            # row format - hash timestamp username currency user_balance withdraw_address withdraw_amount
            withdraw = WithdrawRequests()
            withdraw.withdraw_hash = withdraw_hash,
            withdraw.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(),
            withdraw.username = username,
            withdraw.currency = currency,
            withdraw.user_balance = user_balance,
            withdraw.withdraw_address = withdraw_address,
            withdraw.withdraw_amount = withdraw_amount

            withdraw.save()
```

Comment: I tried this the error after this

django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["“(Decimal('0.01109555556390499908570035358934546820819377899169921875'),)” value must be a decimal number."]

Comment: @MelsHakobyan what if you `print(withdraw_amount)`? What does it print? Also share entire view.

Comment: @MelsHakobyan See edited answer it can work try it out.

Comment: it's a float number not string.

Comment: Entire view is huge

Comment: for i,k in enumerate(user_balance):
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

as I said it's a float

Comment: @MelsHakobyan you need to write for i, k in enumerate(x) not user_balance could you please try again it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice when writing the code but as @AbdulAzizBarkat mentioned the solution was very basic, to remove commas after several lines like so

```
withdraw.withdraw_hash = withdraw_hash,
withdraw.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
withdraw.username = username
withdraw.currency = currency
withdraw.user_balance = user_balance
withdraw.withdraw_address = withdraw_address
```